# MySQL, making a list with unlimited values - correct approach?

Tags: mysql

I just learnt the basics of `MySQL` and I'm wondering about this:

I have a user table with their ID, their Name and Gender.

I want to store an unlimited number of websites for each user but I don't know how to store them or where to put them.

Can I store all sites in one cell, do I create a new column for each site? What would be the correct approach considering that later I'll have to be able to process the info? Like for example check if an user added a particular site, count how many websites each user has, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach would be to create a second table, with two fields - the user ID and the website.

Then when you want to get all the websites for user X, just look up the second table to find all rows where the user ID matches.

Comment: I think I understand that approach. Please tell my if I go it: I would make the two columns and insert a row for each website an user adds (ID, Website). Then I would look all rows that have a user ID to get the websites. Is that right? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to create separate tables.  I think that where you say "database" above, you meant table.  You need to create a `user` table, and then you need to create a `site` table that has a column that references the user table.

Answer (score 1):

Another table with ID and Website as columns perhaps with ID being a foreign key and (website, id) being the primary key